# jQuery (scrolltop) is not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scrolltop

I'm a newbie to wordpress. I'm having problems hooking js/jQ. I did read articles about how to install jQuery.

What I want to do is to make a button that slides when clicking.

And my question is that I used wp_enqueue_script to load the script and put wp_head,wp_footer before `</head>` and `</body>` separately. However, Wordpress put all the script at the bottom of body.

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_loader');


function script_loader() {

    //not sure if I should load the wp jquery fuction//

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-core');


    //Here's the three scripts that I want to hook//

    wp_enqueue_script( 'skrollr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.js', array(), NULL, true);

    wp_enqueue_script( 'init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/init.js', array(), NULL, true);

    //This is the jQuery one 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slide', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slide.js', array('jquery'), NULL, false);   
}
```

Assuming that I'm correct, jQuery suppose to be loaded in the head not end of body, 
so I did tried to use  to call my slide.js in the head(I know it's not the right way), and it did called but slide.js was still not fired

Here's the slide code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(

  function($) {

    $('.down').click(function() {

      var x= $(window).scrollTop();
      var s;

      if (x < 500){
        s = 500;
      }else if(500 <= x && x <700 ){
        s = 700;
      }else if(700 <= x && x < 1000){
        s=1000;
      }else{
        s=1020;
      };

      $('html, body').animate(
        {scrollTop: s}, 1000);

    });
  };

);
```

It is very frustrating because there is no any feedback when you do something wrong, can anyone please help ? :(

Comment: is there any error printed on console?

Comment: nope! It loaded the page well, just the button had no respond when clicking. To be more precise I tried it on codepen it works fine: http://codepen.io/iamkaikai/pen/hIyrc

but not on my wordpress site:
http://rocknshin.net84.net/wordpress/

Comment: try to replace '$' sign with 'jQuery', as '$' is sometimes conflicted with another library. 
Also make sure you included all necessary js and css files. 
Hope this helps. Cheers!!!

Comment: thanks for your help ashu, but still not working:(

Comment: try $(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem is. Turned out that my button was overlapped by other layers, so when I clicked the button, I didn't really click anything.

Just simply change the z-index to bigger value and everything works well. There was nothing wrong with jQuery:)